# Dell XPS 13: won't boot with newest kernel (cannot enter encryption password for ctyptsetup)

Tags: boot, kernel, dell, xps

I am on Ubuntu 15.04.

I have a problem with the latest kernel, which got upgraded a few days ago. This kernel won't boot: `3.19.0-30-generic`

Fortunately I have still the old `3.19.0-28-generic` which boots correctly. I did not do any customization of the kernel.

I have an encrypted main volume, so the first thing I should see is the password prompt. In fact, the first time I reboot, I do see it, but I can't type anything in it: all typing gets silently ignored. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works, though, and the system gets rebooted.

After a reboot, the password prompt won't be shown AT ALL and the screen will stay blank.

Any hint on how could I debug this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported in Ubuntu's bug tracking system, and is affecting multiple users, including Dell XPS 13 owners. Let's hope it gets fixed soon.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1500751